# jQuery: Updating function for window size changes in special case

Tags: jquery

I would like to insert my footer directly under my navigation if the window size is under a width of `1000px` and under a height of `500px`. **In general, it works how I coded it.**

**But:** It doesn't update if the window size changes. If the page gets loaded under this breakpoint, and the `#footer` is under the `#navigation`, it should also switch back to normal mode if the window size gets more than 1000 pixels wide and 500 pixels high.

This is the code:

```js
const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px) and (max-height: 500px)");

if (mq.matches) {
  $("#footer").insertAfter("#navigation");
}
}
```

Would be soooooo thankful for help.

Comment: Is the code you have provided within a function bound to the window.onresize event?

Comment: Hey, no, I wrote this directly in a <script></script> container. But I think something like that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is place the code you have already written inside a function bound t othe window.onresize event.

```js
window.onresize = Resize;
window.onload = Resize;

function Resize(){
    let mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px) and (max-height: 500px)");

    if (mq.matches) {
        $("#footer").insertAfter("#navigation");
    }
    else{
        // Your code to place the footer where it's needed
    }
}
```

This will run the media query you have written every time the page is resized

Comment: That's interesting. Now it works if the window size changes, but it doesn't work if the page is loaded without a window size change.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I will update my answer to fix the first issue. I don't understand what you mean regarding the else, could you try to expand upon what it is you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would work now. My questions is: Do I need something for »else { }« – or is it possible to take the originally position from the HTML file?

Comment: The else{} is used to place the #footer element where you would like it if the page has a width greater than 1000px and a height greater than 500px